# Python Script to send JSON request using the Cookies of the website

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to imitate a authenticated JSON request. I am using the Requests module to do so.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://"
headers = {
    'Host': 'example.com',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

data = {
"asdsdsd": {
    "AppName": "esdf",
    "Language": "EN",
    "fsef": [
        {
            "sfddf": [
                {
                    "sdfsdfsdf": "sdfsdfsdf"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"sdfdf": {
    "sdfsdf": "sdfsdfsdf"
}
}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers ,verify=False)
```

How do i include the authenticated cookie into this.

Can I  open this  request using a browser(with the headers & data) then i would be able to use the authenticated cookie of the browser.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Session` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to manage cookies.

```
s = requests.Session()

# load initial page to get session cookies set, perhaps a CSRF token
loginform = s.get(loginurl)

# post login information to the form
s.post(someurl, data={...})

# post JSON with session with authentication cookie
s.post(someurl, ...)
```

Comment: I am not logging in using the script, i need to send a authenticated request in between, Can I use the cookieLib libraray to get the cookies from the mozila cookie jar ?

Comment: @VinodK: That depends on the browser, and depending on how you want to support various browsers and end users could get a lot more complicated than just using a session and parsing the login page.

Answer (score 0):

```
headers = {
'Host': 'example.com',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

session = requests.session()
session.headers=headers
```

you can use session for post

```
session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data) ,verify=False)
```

Comment: The headers structure is not valid Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data directly into the form of a cookie in your request like this :

```py
data = {
    "sessionid":"yoursessionidorsomethingelseidontcarelolwtfhelloworld"
}
url = "https://youramazingurl.com/list_some_private_data"
res = requests.get(url, cookies=data)
```

Done :)

Comment: Then why didn't he use the cookie argument ? .-.

Comment: Perhaps the OP doesn't *know* about the `cookie` argument? Why didn't you suggest the `request.Session()` option to handle cookies between requests?

Comment: Because if the OP doesn't need to handle sessions but still needs to make a request with a cookie auth, then it could be simpler ? I don't know, that fits the OP needs so why shoud I complicate my answer ? ^^

Comment: Right, the OPs needs weren't clear to me. I was more focussing on the 'there is a login form and a cookie' issue.

Comment: What i want to know is whether i can access the authenticated cookies, or whether i can open the same request (with header & data) using a browser. btw what does OP stand for ?

Comment: It means Original Poster. Which is the person who asked the question. I don't understand your questions in your last comment though. If you want to access the data of the auth cookie you can simply try to turn on debug mode in your broswer (`Ctr+Maj+i` on firefox) and go to the "Cookie" section. That should give you the information you need.